# Content not displaying in JFrame

Tags: java

I have just started working on a small GUI for an assignment, but upon launching it, nothing apart from the title is visible.

My code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;



public class Property extends JFrame 
{
/*private String propertyType;
private String propertyAddress;
private double propertyArea;
private int numOfBedrooms;
private int numOfGarages;
private int numOfToilets;
private String ownerGivenName;
private String ownerSurname;
private String ownerdateOfBirth;*/

    JButton PropertySaleButton = new JButton("Add New Property");
JButton PurchaseOfferButton = new JButton("Submit Purchase Offer");



public Property()
    {
    setLayout (new FlowLayout());

            add(PropertySaleButton);
    add(PurchaseOfferButton);
}

            public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() ->
        {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("CQ Real Estate");
            /*Image img = new ImageIcon("icon.gif").getImage();
            setIconImage(img);*/
            frame.setSize(450, 500);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);

        });
}
}
```

If anyone can tell me what I'm missing it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You only create an empty `JFrame`, you don't create a `Property` instance. Use `JFrame frame = new Property();` at least. (Added as an answer.)

Comment: you are not invoking `new Property()`

Answer (score 0):

`Property` is the class that hold your "GUI design" but didn't use it. You build a `JFrame`. Instead, create a `Property` instace

```
JFrame frame = new Property();
```

You will need to adapt a bit your code (to add the title).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to:

```
this.getContentPane.add(PropertySaleButton);
this.getContentPane.add(PurchaseOfferButton);
```